# html/body 100% height not filling 100% of viewport

Tags: html, css

My html and body elements are not filling 100% of the viewport, which is leaving me with approx 200px of blank space below my footer. I have played with the inspector to try and resolve this problem but nothing is working perfectly.

It is worth noting that I have 3x sidebars that are activated from the top menu (Artists, About, History) and these need to be 100% height too, I feel that this probably has something to do with the issue.

Any help much appreciated, I haven't included any markup here as the problem is quite broad.

Thanks

http://workshop.oakdesignstudio.com/dwl/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: both the html and body tags are larger than 100% of the viewport, about 1300 pixels f you inspect in chrome, so your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: adding position:relative to the body does the trick!

Comment: Adding position: relative; to the body prevents the sidebars from filling 100% of the height?

Comment: @Paulie_D tahnks for the advise, but I'd have to include my entire site code to replicate the issue so in this instance it seems justified to supply a live link.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is to give your body `position: relative;`

So

```
html{ 
 height: 100%;
} 

body{
 height 100%;
 position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Adding position: relative; to the body prevents the sidebars from filling 100% of the height?

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to give position value to your footer tag.
add this code on line no. 475

```
footer {
 position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The page structure is really important especially for cross-browser compatibilty. This will help with your sidebars as well;

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
}
#content {
    padding-bottom:100px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Original source http://www.cssreset.com/demos/layouts/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

Try it yourself and you'll be thankful for that layout structure!

Comment: Hi, thnaks for your suggestion. However, this doesn't seem to have made any kind of difference to my site. The sidebars are refusing to fill 100% height.