# Cannot force absolutely positioned elements to fill 100% of viewport/site

Tags: html, css

I am unable to force a couple of my elements to be 100% height of the browser window. I want `.blank` and `.sidebar` to fill 100% height regardless of how much content they hold (any overflow should be taken care of by using `overflow-y: scroll;`

Thanks!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhkw7kcp/1/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <aside class="sidebar about">
      <h5>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h5>
      <h5>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h5>
  </aside>
  <div class="blank"></div>

  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <h5>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h5>
    <h5>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h5>
    <h5>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h5>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </footer>


</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: grey;
    color: white;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 76px;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 80px 60px;
    z-index: 3;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: black;
}

.blank {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 0%, cyan 75%);
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 28px;
    position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  padding: 24px 0px;
    z-index: 4;
}

main {
    margin: 76px 0 150px 0;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
  height: 175px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I've copied your code to http://codepen.io/jaycrisp/pen/OMoEaM and the 2 divs are taller than 100% of the browser height, so I'm not sure what your problem is. However,using absolute positioning for layout like this isn't a great idea. It's not going to be responsive and will break easily if/when the content changes.

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to get the .blank and .sidebar elements (which are both absolutely positioned) to always be 100% height of the browser (even when scrolled, not just based on the initial viewport. Even if there is just one word in a sidebar I still want the black background to extend to the full height. If there is too much content I want it to scroll.

Comment: Here is a live example that might help to explain, please activate .blank and .sidebar by clicking the menu at top (artists, about, history) - my fiddle was simplified. workshop.oakdesignstudio.com/dwl/artists/anna-pancaldi

Comment: Did you ask the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202155/html-body-100-height-not-filling-100-of-viewport ?

Comment: Do you want the sidebar to stay in the same position when the browser is scrolled? if so, you need to use position: fixed instead of absolute

Comment: Hi @JamieC, that is my question but it resolved one of the issues which was the positioning of the footer. The code has changed and the problem different.

Comment: @JamieC yes the sidebar should remain constant but the content within it may or may not be scrollable. Either way the height should always be 100%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102611/discussion-between-jamiec-and-dungey-140).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[use vh its for viewport height.](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

so instead of

```
height: 100%;
```

use

```
height: 100vh;
```

and set fix heights for mediaqueries below ~768px height because especially ios and some other browsers cannot handle it.

[see browser which can viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)

another solution would be with jquery but i dont recommend using jquery for this case.

cannot show you the updated fiddle cause there the rendered page is not the whole viewport..

---

update:

you need to set the sidebar this css:

```
.sidebar {
    width: calc(50% - 160px);
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 76px;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-right: -100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 30px 80px 60px;
    z-index: 3;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: black;
    -webkit-transition: margin-right 1.2s ease;
    transition: margin-right 1.2s ease;
}
```

greetings timotheus

Comment: Hi. This doesn't seem to work for me, when I begin to scroll down the page the .blank and .sidebar elements are still not 100% of <body>

Comment: Here is a live example that might help to explain, please activate .blank and .sidebar by clicking the menu at top (artists, about, history) - my fiddle was simplified.

http://workshop.oakdesignstudio.com/dwl/artists/anna-pancaldi/

Comment: ya, its because you have a padding-top and bottom and also set a top value... in your case you could set "box-sizing: border-box;" for letting the padding expand inside not outside and set the height to to less vh because of the top value

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas regarding .blank?

Comment: you want that the page isnt scrollable when menu is open?